# The unknown crush my android app using viewpager and fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, native

Here's [a link](http://jubayer.eu5.org/json/test.txt) my complete code of my android project.
There i am using viewpager with 3 fragment . In first fragment i have an edittext and a button..when i click buttn it send data to hosting activity then from hosting activity i send the data to second activity and show the data in textview....third fragment is simply plain page.

when run my program and write something in edittext in first fragment and click button it send data to 2nd fragment as i expected but problem is that if i visit third fragment and then come to the first fragment do the same task as stated above my program crushes rather than send data to 2nd fragment.

its shows the following error in log

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(773): Process: com.example.swipeapp, PID: 773
    E/AndroidRuntime(773): java.lang.ClassCastException:  
    com.example.swipeapp.FirstActivity cannot be cast tocom.example.swipeapp.SecondActivity
    E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at           com.example.swipeapp.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:38)
    E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.example.swipeapp.FirstActivity$1.onClick(FirstActivity.java:31)
    E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    E/AndroidRuntime(773):at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
```

Please give me any suggestion why this app cruses any tutorial or documantion on this is appreciated.....thanks in advance :)

here is my fragment adapter code

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter{

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment fragment = new FirstActivity();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new FirstActivity();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecondActivity();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ThirdActivity();
        break;

    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    String title = "";
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        title = "First Fragment";
        break;
    case 1:
        title = "Second";
        break;
    case 2:
        title = "Third";
        break;

    }
    return title;
}
```

}

Comment: actually you trying to cast from first fragment to second fragment which is illegal, i know how to fix this and give you a solution but it's too long somehow

Comment: Please give me any kind of documentation link or tutorial that explain my sutiation or at least tell me where i am doing wrong so i can rather search on this topics @NoXSaeeD

Comment: your problem is here `SecondActivity rf = (SecondActivity) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.pager);` in sendData funtion, you calling `findFragmentById` using pager id and pager contain first fragment not second fragment

Comment: if so then how it works when i click on the button and send data to second fragment....I think you don't understand my question.....my app work fine until i go to the third fragment.... if i go third fragment and then come to the first fragment and click the button then the app crush otherwise it works fine .... @NoXSaeed

Comment: i wish you solve your problem good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
switch(position){
case 0:
    fragment = new FirstActivity();
    break;
case 1:
    fragment = new SecondActivity();
    break;
case 2:
    fragment = new ThirdActivity();
    break;

}
return fragment;
}
```

Comment: what you actually try to do :O @Dev Carlsberg